# Is it possible to trigger an azure function on a random schedule?

Tags: azure-functions

I am creating an Azure function and would like it to run with a random delay between each run. I want the delay between each run to be randomly selected from the interval 10 - 20 minutes. For example, I want:

- function run
- 11 min delay
- function run
- 17 min delay
- function run
- 10 min delay
- function run
- 20 min delay
- etc ...

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you were open to some really hacky methods, [this article](https://contos.io/randomized-schedules-in-azure-functions-fec2abb087c3) seems relevant. This person rewrites their `function.json` file to replace the existing `schedule` with a randomized one. Otherwise, if you had a way to store a persistent value (locally or a DB), you could choose a random number between 10 and 20, add that many minutes to the current time, store it, and with each run of your function, check if the current minute is equal to that minute. If not, exit. If so, run the function, generate new random time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Do not modify the `functions.json`

Do not modify the `functions.json` as suggested. It restarts your entire function app, which in my case (using Node.js) also means that I am getting charged a small but noticeable amount of money for reading/writing tens of thousands of files in my `node_modules` folder.

## Solution

Your best bet is to run the function each minute, but exit immediately most of the time. Here's an example. I assume we want to run the function randomly, but on average we want to run the function every 15 minutes.

### Node.js

```
// On average, run the function every N minutes:
const AVERAGE_RUN_EVERY=15;

if (Math.random() > 1 / AVERAGE_RUN_EVERY) {
  // Most of the time, we will exit here:
  context.done();
} else {
  // Your actual code here
}
```

### .NET

```
int AVERAGE_RUN_EVERY = 15;
Random rnd = new Random();
if (rnd.Next(0, AVERAGE_RUN_EVERY) == 0) {
  // Your actual code here
}
```

## Extra costs for running randomly

Assuming the minimum charge for each execution is 100ms and the memory used by your application is 256 MB or less, every month you will get charged:

> 0.1s * 0.25 GB * 1440 minutes/day * 30 days * $0.000016/GB/s = 0.02 USD

Actually, you may even end up saving money because you function app will not enter sleep mode if it's running each minute, meaning that the function will consume less time for the startup.

Comment: Thanks, is it supposed to be "if (rnd.Next(0, AVERAGE_RUN_EVERY) == 0)" instead of "> 0" since "> 0" will almost always be true

Answer (score 2):

Durable Function is the way to go. But instead of using a loop, you can use the `ContinueAsNew()` method in `IDurableOrchestrationContext`. This will make the orchestration start over, which prevents your orchestration history table becoming overly long from using a simple loop.

Also, the orchestrator needs to be deterministic, so you shouldn't use random number generators or call `DateTime.Now` in the orchestrator.

```cs
[FunctionName("Orchestrator")]
public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    int delay = await context.CallActivityAsync<int>("Activity", null);
    await context.CreateTimer(context.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(delay), CancellationToken.None);
    context.ContinueAsNew(null);
}

[FunctionName("Activity")]
public static int DoActivity([ActivityTrigger] object input, ILogger log)
{
    // Do whatever you want to do at random intervals.
    return new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(1, 60);
}
```

By the way, due to how durable orchestration works, there is actually no function running when you await on the timer you created in the orchestrator, so you wouldn't be charged during the delay. You are still charged for await time spent in client and activity functions though.

More information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-eternal-orchestrations

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with Durable Functions using the `CreateTimer` method.

Example:

```
public static async Task Run(DurableOrchestrationContext ctx)
{
   //Do some work here

    while (true) 
    {
        // Orchestration will sleep until this time
        var nextCheck = ctx.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddSeconds(randomNumber);
        await ctx.CreateTimer(nextCheck, CancellationToken.None);
        //Call the function again


    } 
}
```

You can read more about it here [Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-overview)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if I will be charged for cpu/memory time spent in the await?

Comment: I believe it will be charged since the function will be executing even if it was not doing anything

Comment: @user3912349 You are definitely getting charged for the await time. If I have a few async calls to make, I do them in parallel to reduce the idle awaiting time.